# how to build a recursively JSON from from string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that could be in this form : **'school,room,teacher,pencil'** or it could be **'school,room,teacher'** .

What I want to do is after splitting the string , every word should have this structure :

**{node:word,group:word-1,groupN:word-2 ...}**

For example for the word **room** the structure would be **{node:"room",group:"school"}**

for the word **teacher** it would be **{node:"teacher",group:"room",groupN:"school"}**

for the word **pencil** it would be **{word:"pencil",group:"teacher",groupN:"room",groupNN:"school"}**

I did like that but it's not standard way :

```
 var str="xxx,xxx,xxx,xxx"
 var splitedStr = str.split(",")
       for(var i=0;i<splitedStr.length;i++) {
           var data = {node :splitedStr[i],group:splitedStr[i-1],groupN:splitedStr[i-2]}
       }
```

Please do you have any idea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const getJson= (elName, textElements) => {
  const elements = textElements.split(',');
  const elementIdx = elements.findIndex(el => el===elName)
  let result = {room:elName}
  if (elementIdx>=0)
    elements.slice(0,elementIdx).map((el, idx)=>{
      result['group'+Array(elementIdx - idx).join("N") ] = el
    })
  return result
}
```

Ad use like this:

```
const arr = 'school,room,teacher,pencil'
console.log(getJson('room', arr))
console.log(getJson('teacher', arr))
console.log(getJson('pencil', arr))
```